# Calling a function continuously within a loop and printing different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, credentials

I am creating a small program that pulls quotes of a certain artist and then posts a random line from a random song of theirs onto Twitter. I have so far managed to pull the lyrics, get a random line from a random song but it always posts the same lyric. I understand why this is happening as it isn't only looping through the same output earlier on. Could you advise how I can get the loop to pull a new song and then a new random lyric each time it loops round? I have tried to call the 'lyricsimport' function within the loop to no avail

I'm quite new to Python please feedback any improvements if necessary - thank you in advance

Here is my code so far...

```
# Import Twitter credentials from credentials.py
import random
from tswift import Artist
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials import *

# Access and authorize our Twitter credentials from credentials.py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#get lyrics from tswift and save to text file
def lyricsimport():
    tswift = Artist('Frank Ocean')
    song = random.choice(tswift.songs)
    savefile = open('ocean.txt', 'w')
    savefile.write(song.format())
    savefile.close()


# Open text file ocean.txt (or your chosen file) for reading and select random lyric
with open('ocean.txt') as f:
    my_file = f.readlines()
    file_lines = random.choice(my_file)

# Tweet a line every 10 seconds (will change post-testing)
def tweet():
    # Create a for loop to iterate over file_lines
    for line in file_lines:
        try:
            print(file_lines)
            #if statement to ensure that blank lines are skipped
            if line != '\n':
                api.update_status(file_lines)
                sleep(10)
            else:
                pass
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
            sleep(2)
tweet()
```

Comment: When you open you file with 'w' flag, you write a new file every time you call lyricsimport. It will then always contain only one single song and therefor tweet the same over and over again as random choice always chooses that one. If you call open with 'a' flag, the write command appends to the file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: If I were able to loop through the line `savefile = open('ocean.txt', 'w')` would this provide different results each time?

Answer (score 1):

`my_file` is all the lines in the file, right?
and so `file_lines` is a `random.choice` from those, and `random.choice` only returns a single value... This should be visible by 
`print(file_lines)` - should be just a single line.

How about you replace

```
    api.update_status(file_lines)
```

in your loop with

```
    api.update_status(random.choice(my_file))
```

?

The file opening should look like this:

```
with open('ocean.txt') as f:
    my_file = f.readlines()
```

And let's see if that helps :)

Comment: yes, my_file is all the lines and random.choice only returns a single value which is as expected

I added your code to the 'with open(...)' block here:
`with open('ocean.txt') as f:
 my_file = f.readlines()
 file_lines = api.update_status(random.choice(my_file))`
with error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterbot_textfile_oneline.py", line 42, in <module>
    tweet()
  File "twitterbot_textfile_oneline.py", line 30, in tweet
    for line in file_lines:
TypeError: 'Status' object is not iterable`

Comment: Thanks - so I've updated it as above and it is printing out the entire song - I will paste the changes I made as I moved the print to copy the output to twitter...

`random lyric
with open('ocean.txt') as f:
 my_file = f.readlines()


def tweet():
 for line in my_file:
  try:
      #if statement to ensure that blank lines are skipped
   if line != '\n':
    api.update_status(random.choice(my_file))
    print(my_file)
    sleep(10)
   else:
    pass
  except tweepy.TweepError as e:
   print(e.reason)
   sleep(2)
tweet()`